# Java: difficulties making fade out animation run without being refreshed by processing

Tags: java, animation, processing

I have a simple animation play of a circle scale outwards and fade out whenever the applications detects that the hammer object has reached a certain angle. However, as it is currently implemented the animation will only play once. I have attempted using for loops to allow the animation to complete, but this causes the entire application to pause while the code is looped, and other attempts I have made have not worked, so any help at all would be appreciated.

```
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;

float bx;
float by;
int boxSizeX = 160;
int boxSizeY = 30;
boolean overBox = true;
boolean locked = false;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0; 
float angle = 4.70;
float cooldown;
int alphaVal = 255;
int colorchange = 0;

//for sound effect
float a = 0.0;
float s = 0.0;

BeatBall b1 = new BeatBall(210,425,60, 1);
BeatBall b2 = new BeatBall(570,395,60, 2);
Hammer h = new Hammer(135, -67,  boxSizeY+25, boxSizeX-25, 1);

void setup()
{
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
  frameRate(120);
  bx = width/2.0;
  by = height/2.0;

    oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12001);

  /* myRemoteLocation is a NetAddress. a NetAddress takes 2 parameters,
   * an ip address and a port number. myRemoteLocation is used as parameter in
   * oscP5.send() when sending osc packets to another computer, device, 
   * application. usage see below. for testing purposes the listening port
   * and the port of the remote location address are the same, hence you will
   * send messages back to this sketch.
   */
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",12000);
}

void draw()
{ 
  background(0);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  float mx = constrain(angle, -2.6075916, -0.5207284);

  ///////////////////////////
  //THIS IS THE ANIMATION //
  //////////////////////////
  if(locked)
  {

    a = a + 0.02;
    s = cos(a)*10;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(210,425);
    scale(s); 
    fill(colorchange, 30, 150, alphaVal);
    ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50); 
    alphaVal = alphaVal - 3;
    colorchange = colorchange + 3;
    popMatrix();
  }

  pushMatrix();
  translate(400, 425);
  rotate(mx);
  fill(222,223,255);
  h.displayHammer();
  rect(-25, -15, boxSizeX, boxSizeY);
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix();
  translate(595, 390);
  rotate(radians(58));  
  fill(122,78,163);
  rect(0, 0, 50, 50);  
  popMatrix();


  b1.displayBall(); 

  //b2.displaySquare();



  cooldown = cooldown + 0.01;
  println(cooldown);

  if(mx == -2.6075916)
   {
     if(cooldown > 0.5)
     {
      locked = true;
      soundEffect();
      b1.collide();
      cooldown = 0; 
     }     
   }
   else if(mx == -0.5207284)
   {
     if(cooldown > 0.5)
     {

      b1.collide();
      cooldown = 0; 
     }     
   }
}

void soundEffect()
{

}


void mousePressed() 
{
  xOffset = mouseX-bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-by; 
}

void mouseDragged()
{
   angle = atan2(mouseY - 400, mouseX - 400);
   println(angle);
}
```

Comment: When are you resetting the animation?

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified that right now the animation doesn't end but simply fades out to complete transparency.

Comment: Then you have to reset the animation. When do you want the animation to start over?